# JumpList.GetJumpList does not contain recent items

Tags: c#, wpf, jump-list, recent-file-list

So, my WPF application has a jump list defined in `App.xaml`

```
<JumpList.JumpList>
    <JumpList ShowRecentCategory="True"/>
</JumpList.JumpList>
```

This list is empty, unless windows recognizes certain files associated with my application. I managed to associate my custom file extension via Inno Setup and the jump list shows nicely in the win7 start menu + taskbar. Clicking on such a "recent file" calls my application with an additional command line argument (the filename) and I can open that file directly on application startup.

**Goal: Show recent files inside the application (not just on the win7 taskbar).**
Think of the File menu (e.g. Visual Studio: File > Recent Files > ...) or something like a start page showing recent projects to jump into.

**Problem: JumpList only contains custom tasks, not the recent files.** It is possible to iterate over the JumpItems via

```
List<JumpItem> items = JumpList.GetJumpList(Application.Current).JumpItems
```

which is a list of JumpTask / JumpPath instances. I do find custom created tasks here (e.g. if I define one in `App.xaml`), but not the recent files that show up in windows (start menu / taskbar). So in my case windows shows the 10 most recent files, but in the application I can't find a way to display them.

If I ommit the JumpList definition from `App.xaml` the above call will return null instead of a JumpList (thought, I've overwritten the win7 JumpList, but no).

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually add the recent item to the jumplist

```
var jumpTask = new JumpTask
{
    Title = fileName,
    Arguments = fullPath
};
JumpList.AddToRecentCategory(jumpTask)
```

Comment: I know how to manually add extra items from my application. The question is: How can I get the jump list items from windows?